# pass jsp variable to external js using jsp tag lib

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I am able to pass variable from jsp to js using below code. Someone told me it is better to use jsp tag lib instead of doing this way. I tried googling but couldn't find a solution. Can someone please explain what jsp tag lib is ? And how can I pass variable from jsp to js using jsp tag lib ?

```
<script>
var jsVariable = "${jspVariable}";
alert( jsVariable ); //test the value
</script>
```

Comment: This just means separating the JavaScript into a separate file and including it as a taglib.

Comment: @davidcondrey javascript or jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the value of a JavaScript variable that way.

```
<c:set var="jspVariable" value="${7}"/>

<script>
    var jsVariable = "${jspVariable}";
    alert( jsVariable ); //test the value
</script>
```

What is JSTL you can find here, for example: [About JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)